# Print Folders Missing .txt Filetype

Tags: linux, files, filenames

I have 150 directories in a parent directory. Some of them have `.txt` files, others do not. I would like to print which folders do NOT have a `.txt` file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for dir in */; do
    set -- "$dir"/*.txt
    [ ! -e "$1" ] && printf '%s\n' "$dir"
done
```

This loops over all directories in the current directory.  For each directory, it tries to expand a filename globbing pattern that would match all the `.txt` files in that directory, using `set`.  This sets the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) to the pathnames of the files that matches the pattern, or it sets just `$1` to the pattern itself if it does not match anything.  If the first result of that filename expansion is not the pathname of an existing file, the name of the directory is printed.

---

To do this recursively for all directories in the current directory (including the current directory):

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '
    for dir do
        set -- "$dir"/*.txt
        [ ! -e "$1" ] && printf "%s\n" "$dir"
    done' sh {} +
```

This uses `find` as a generator of directory pathnames.  For batches of found directory pathnames, the same loop as earlier is executed, printing the pathname of each directory that does not contain any files whose name end in `.txt`.

---

Note that both above pieces of code will detect the absence of *any* name ending in `.txt`.  If you are just interested in *regular files* (or symbolic links to regular files), then use the following as the body of the loop:

```
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ ! -f "$1" ]; do
    shift
done
[ ! -e "$1" ] && ...as above...
```

---

To include *hidden* filenames, use, for example, `bash -O dotglob -c` in place of `sh -c` with `find`.  This will make the filename globbing in the shell loop also consider names starting with a dot.  In the first variation, make sure to set the `dotglob` shell option with `shopt -s dotglob` if you are running the loop in `bash`.

Comment: Why do we need `sh` in the last line?

Comment: @WeijunZhou When you run `sh -c` with an in-line script and give it further arguments, the _first_ argument will go into `$0`.  This string will be used by the shell in any error messages.  The rest of the arguments are assigned to the positional parameters. Note that `$0` is _not_ part of the positional parameters, so leaving the `sh` string out would cause the loop to skip the first directory in each batch that it receives from `find`.

Comment: Now that you have considered "regular vs irregular files", why not consider "dotglob" as well?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

search_dir=~/tmp

dirs=( $( find "$search_dir" -type f -name "*.txt" -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u ) )
exclude=()

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    exclude+=( -not -path "$dir" )
done

find "$search_dir" "${exclude[@]}"  -type d
```

Change the `search_dir` variable to the parent directory you want to work with.

It will then set the `dirs` array to every directory that **does** contain .txt files.

Then each of those directories will be added to the `exclude` array in a format that can be fed to `find`.  We then search your parent directory again for all directories that are not in the exclude array.